# Как получить id пользователя joomla, зная логин?

Tags: joomla, php

Всем привет. Люди, подскажите плиз, как получить id пользователя, зная его login?

```
$userid =& JFactory::getUser('username'); 
echo $userid->get('id');//ни в этом, 
echo $userid->id; // и ни в этом случае не выводятся корректные идентификаторы.
```

Выводится 0. Хотя в многих доках написано, что getUser() принимает как числовые параметры (если передавать id, то работает ), так строковые. Странно все это. Может есть еще способы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$user = & JFactory::getUser()->id; // для активного пользователя
```

Помогло

Comment: как это относится к сабжу?

Answer (score 1):

```
$uid = JUserHelper::getUserId($login); // Joomla 3
```